# Is the Nimbus theme for OpenJDK 11 (Linux) buggy?

Tags: java, nimbus, openjdk-11

I was working with some old Java apps which use the Nimbus theme, when suddenly this buggy controls make an appearance:

[image: Nimbus-themed frame with buggy controls]

This started happening when I updated from OpenJDK 8 to OpenJDK 11 (I am working on Linux).

Everything else works as expected, including other themes.

I tried reinstalling OpenJDK, no improvements.

<s>Is this an isolated case? Any ideas about how could I solve it (I cannot downgrade to JDK8)?</s> (See edit)

---

#### Edit (2019-05-06)

I have tried the same binary in a clean virtual machine, and it works perfectly well, so I guess I might have a problem in my system.

I have KDE Neon 18.04.1 64-bit, GPU AMD RX470 with default drivers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try openjdk-12 ?

Comment: Find the path that is being used. You can change it to the one you wish. https://askubuntu.com/questions/772235/how-to-find-path-to-java

Comment: How do you specify nimbus look-and-feel? From what I see at https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/ it changed from `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` to `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`.

Comment: @NoDataFound I tried with JDK8 and worked, will not try  no-LTS version.
@acarlstein I do not get the point of your comment, Java works perfectly well, I have no other installations of Java, the path is set to the right binaries.
@Pshemo I use `UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()` so I can properly set `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(themePackage.getClassName());` after comparing if it is installed.

Comment: @DavidTaberneroM.: my remark was to see if the bug is still there. You could probably also try Java 9 and Java 10, to see where it come from.

Comment: @NoDataFound Ok, I have just tried them in a clean VM and everything works. I edited the question accordingly.